# Help with top-level domain understand

Tags: domain-name-system, tld

I have a uni assignment question that I am having trouble trying to google...

I have been asked to provide 3 lists (i only need a handful of countries for each list) of examples of countries which:

1. Like Australia (.au) echo the gTLD's (.com, .net, etc) under their ccTLD.
2. Like New Zealand/UK (.uk, .nz) are simmilar but not the same as the gTLD's (.co, .ac, etc) under their ccTLD.
3. Like France (.fr) dont echo them at all in any way (France doesnt have any generic domain zones under their ccTLD).

Obviously I know of those 4 - but i need a couple more for each of those 3 types of ccTLDs - can anyone help me?

Comment: Wrong: there are SLD under .fr such as com.fr or nom.fr (nom == name)

Comment: The [List of TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) says if they allow SLDs or if they have the categories. You'd have to look at each one though to determine what pattern the category SLDs follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look through the domains available at one of the more prolific registrars. Here's one that allows registration for a very large number of domains, I'm sure you can find what you need there:

http://www.nameisp.com/advancedsearch.asp